# Template<> not working or for ints

Tags: c++, templates

Here is the code I am having trouble with it seems to work logically but perhaps I am missing a small detail as it doesn't work for chars or ints.
Whenever I run it I get weird output like all Fs or all As.

```
#include <iostream>
template<class T>
char gradeIt(T mark,T maxMark){
    T grade =(mark/maxMark)*100;
    if(grade > 79)
        return 'A';
    else if(grade<=79 && grade >= 69) {
        return 'B';
    }
    else if(grade<=69 && grade>59)
        return 'C';
    else if(grade>50 && grade <=59)
        return 'D';
    else 
        return 'F';
}   
template<>
char gradeIt<char>(char mark,char maxMark){
    return mark;
```

}

Comment: It looks like `mark/maxMark` is performing integer division, which will round to 0 every time. You should static_cast<double>(mark)/maxMark

Comment: I known that is there any way to make it work for floats and intergers

Comment: Unrelated to your immediate problem, but read [this](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) and then change that specialization to an overload.

Answer (score 4):

> T grade =(mark/maxMark)*100;

When the template parameter `T` is `int` this is performing integer division. For example, 80 / 100 = 0.

You could instead do.

```
T grade = mark * 100 / maxMark;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like

```
(mark/maxMark)*100
```

is performing integer division, which will round to 0 every time.

You should `static_cast<double>(mark)/maxMark` to first convert to floating point so you don't lose any digits after the decimal place.

Comment: I forget about static cast,brain fart.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't doing what you want for integers.

```
T grade =(mark/maxMark)*100;
```

In the case of integer division (int and char have the same behavior in this) maxMark is greater than mark then the result will just be 0.

For example

```
int x = 100;
int y = 5;
int z = y/x;
assert(z==0);
```